# Sql-Sqlite Syntax error

Tags: sql

Agradezco sus comentarios sobre como solucionar este error.

(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "idCiudad": syntax error
SQL:

````
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LugarNuevo (
             idLugar int PRIMARY KEY,
             calle varchar(20),
             numero int,
             codigo int,
             idCiudad int,                            
             FOREING KEY (idCiudad) REFERENCES Ciudad(id)
 );]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LugarNuevo;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ciudad;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LugarNuevo (
             idLugar int PRIMARY KEY,
             calle varchar(20),
             numero int,
             codigo int,
             idCiudad int,                            
             FOREING KEY (idCiudad) REFERENCES Ciudad(id)
 );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ciudad (
              id int PRIMARY KEY,
              NombreCiudad varchar(20),
              idPais int,                             
              FOREING KEY (idPais) REFERENCES Pais(id)
````

Comment: Como esperas que referencia IdCiudad con una tabla que todavia no existe?

Comment: Como menciona @gbianchi , estás creando primero la tabla LugarNuevo la cual referencia a la tabla Ciudad, recuerda que el script se lee de arriba hacia abajo ;)

Comment: Por otro lado, se escribe FOREIGN, tienes invertidas la G y la N.

Comment: Tal cual dicen en comentarios, la solución sería primero crear la tabla Ciudad para luego hacer referencia con la restricción de FOREIGN KEY apuntando hacia la columna Id.